# classification of adjectives

Tags: adjective-ending

I got this below exercise online. Before this I had gone through the three groups([link](http://www.learn-german-smarter.com/learn-german-adjective-endings/)) of adjective endings. But I am stuck at this kind of mixed sentences(i.e both ein and adjectives come together) as I am not able to put them in those classifications. Under which group below adjectives comes?

> Ich wünsche euch einen ____ Tag und eine ___ Nacht. [schön / gut]

Comment: First, check the count of *Tag* and *Nacht*. If singular, remember their gender. Check the case which goes with *wünschen*. Then see there's *einen/eine* in front of the adjective.

Comment: I didn't get it. Answer or some links would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich wünsche euch einen ____ Tag und eine ___ Nacht. [schön / gut]

You have to collect some information about the sentence first.

The count of *Tag* and *Nacht*. It's both singular, so you have to know their gender: It's *der Tag* and *die Nacht*.

The verb *wünschen*. That verb takes up to two objects: an accusative object, which is the thing wished, and an optional dative object which is the person whom the wish should be granted. The dative is *euch* here, so *einen _ Tag und eine _ Nacht* has to be the accusative object. One could guess that from *einen* und *eine*, too. Dative would be *einem* und *einer*.

You know that table with the indefinite article **ein**, and you have collected all the necessary information, so you can fill in the declined adjectives:

> Ich wünsche euch einen schön**en** Tag und eine gut**e** Nacht.

---

Edit: relevant declension tables

```
»ein«            | »einige/mehrere/viele etc.«
     m   f   n   | p 
nom  -   e   -   | - 
gen  es  er  es  | r
dat  em  er  em  | n
acc  en  e   -   | -

»adjective predeced by ein/einige/mehrere etc.«
     m   f   n   p
nom  er  e   es  e
gen  en  en  en  er
dat  en  en  en  en
acc  en  e   es  e
```

Comment: So is it that I can decide it by looking at the ein table and fill for the schön and gut? I mean endings of ein and schön are same?

Comment: Right, you have to look at the *»ein preceded adjective«* table because you have an *ein* preceding the adjective. And wrong, the endings of *ein* and the adjective aren't the same. *Ein/einige/viele* etc. itself has a different declension.

Comment: Ok, Now I got it.